# SQL- How do I return just one entry for each date between a date range?

Tags: sql, database

I have a table with multiple entries for each date for example

```
01-may-17 
01-may-17
02-may-17
02-may-17
02-may-17
03-may-17
03-may-17
```

I want to return just one row for each date with associated columns instead all multiple entries from the same date.

How would I do this?
I have

```
select  trunc(colTime) from table 
Where colTime >= ('01-jan-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY') and colTime <=('20-mar-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

But this returns multiple entries for the one date instead of just the one entry per day.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: group by date_column

Comment: Add some more columns to the sample table data, and also adjust the result.

Comment: try my answer @Newbie2015Giant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ANSI-standard function `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Your code looks like Oracle.  For the full query, I would recommend:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by trunc(colTime) order by colTime) as seqnum
      from table t
      Where colTime >= date '2017-01-01' and coltime <= date '2017-03-20'
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Notes:

- Learn to use the `date` keyword.  It allows you to input ISO-standard date formats.
- The `order by` as states returns the first record for each day.  You can use `colTime desc` to get the last record.

Answer (score 0):

simple use **GROUP BY**

```
select  * from table 
Where colTime >= ('01-jan-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY') and colTime <=('20-mar-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY')  
group by colTime;
```